# Windows Firewall - Laravel Artisan Serve - Allow Port in Inbound Rule (not working)

Tags: windows, laravel, port, firewall, serve

I'm using Laravel..And i develop a website... And I want try to access the site from other devices....

.

.

I run `php artisan serve --port=4042 --host=0.0.0.0` in my computer (windows 10)..

And I allow port 4042 by create new `Inbound Rules` in Windows Firewall (as in picture below):
[image]

But when I access from my mobile phone, it shows error as in picture below:
[image]

But I can access the web if I turn off the whole Firewall....
[image]

But I dont want disable the whole Firewall, I just want to allow port 4042 only)....

Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What a silly mistake.... I just found the problem after hours googling and searching the solution.

The problem is the Firewall block `php.exe` program.... I don't know at what time I add that rule... So, i just delete that rule...And the problem solved.

[image]

Comment: thanks for following up with the solution - it gave me the clue I needed for why a rule I created wasn't working. In my case apparently the app installer for the application serving the port had created rules to block incoming ports on public networks, which were overriding my rule.

Comment: thanks!! you literally saved my day... my case was Python `http.server` not working